# Как обращаться тэгам в Protractor?

Tags: тестирование

```
// Find an element using a css selector.
by.css('.myclass') 

// Find an element with the given id.
by.id('myid')

// Find an element with a certain ng-model.
// Note that at the moment, this is only supported for AngularJS apps.
by.model('name')

// Find an element bound to the given variable.
// Note that at the moment, this is only supported for AngularJS apps.
by.binding('bindingname')
```

на официальном сайте есть такая документация. а как обращаться тэгам. например я делаю авторизацию (пустые поля) и хочу проверить есть ли текст.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

К тегам можно обратиться следующим образом:

```
element(by.tagName('a'))
```

или

```
$('a')
```

Если Вам нужно проверить текст внутри тега на соответствие:

```
expect(element(by.tagName('a')).getText()).toEqual('текст');
```

или

```
expect($('a').getText()).toEqual('текст');
```

Получение самого текста:

```
$('a').getText().then((text) => {
   console.log(text);
})
```